# clojure.data.json/write: application of predicate to determine value quoting

Tags: json, clojure

Suppose I have a simple map, `example-map`:

```
(def example-map {"a" "b" "c" "d"})
```

I can use `clojure.data.json/write-str` to JSON-ify this map as such:

```
(clojure.data.json/write-str example-map) =>
"{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":\"d\"}"
```

I would like to apply a predicate to all keys to determine if that key is quoted, even if the output is invalid `JSON`.

The desired function would work as follows:

```
(defn to-quote? [v] (= v "d"))

(fictional-write-str example-map :quote-rule to-quote?) =>
"{\"a\":\"b\",\"c\":d}"
```

Might the optional [`:value-fn`](http://clojure.github.io/data.json/) parameter to `clojure.data.json/write-json` offer what I'm describing?

Comment: Just a note: if you ever find yourself returning `true` and `false` out of an `if`-like structure, then you dont need the `if` at all. `(not (eq? v "d"))` is identical to your code.

Comment: Also `eq?` is not a function that exists at all in Clojure. You just want `=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`write-str` works via protocol `JSONWriter`, which you can extend with, say, `clojure.lang.Symbol` and have you own way.

```
(ns reagenttest.main
    (:refer-clojure :exclude (read))
    (:require [clojure.data.json :as json]))

(defn- write-named [x out]
    (.print out (name x)))

(extend clojure.lang.Symbol json/JSONWriter {:-write write-named})

(prn (json/write-str {"a" 'd "b" "c" "e" :key}))
```

shows

```
"{\"a\":d,\"b\":\"c\",\"e\":\"key\"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use clojure.data.json to write things that are not json. What is the point? Conforming parsers will correctly refuse to parse the nonsense you write. This is why it is not easy to do, i.e. there is nothing built into the library to allow you to do it. You can maybe cheat by embedding objects with special types for which you implement JSONWriter, but again, this is very strongly discouraged.

Why do you want to do this? There is surely a more reasonable way to solve your actual problem; "How do I get a JSON library to output invalid JSON" is the wrong starting point.

Comment: That's a great point, @amalloy. My purpose of outputting what's obviously invalid `JSON` follows the need to work with another piece of software that will interpolate quoted values into appropriate fields. It seems the lazy solution here is short sighted. I'll try to implement a custom parser to do the trick.